# Laravel 5.2 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

I am trying to show my data from two database tables and I get the error message Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Anyone know how I solve this get error?

**NB: I am new in laravel**

**Here is my Controller:**

```
$post = PostModel::find($post_id);
$comment = new CommentModel;
```

**My PostModel:**

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CommentModel');
}
```

**my CommentModel:**

```
 public function post() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\PostModel');
    }
```

**My view page where I want to display my database models on:**

```
 @foreach($post->comments as $comment)  
<div class="comment"> 
    <div class="author-info">
        <div class="author-name">
            <h4>{{ $comment->name }}</h4>
        </div>      
    </div>      
    <div class="comment-content">
        {{ $comment->comment }}     
    </div>  
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Here is my comment table**

```
public function up() 
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->text('comment');
    $table->boolean('approved');
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
  });

    Schema::table('comments', function ($table){
          $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
         });
     }


     public function down()
     {
         Schema::dropForeign(['post_id']);
         Schema::drop('comments');
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relation defined with **belongsTo()** returns only one object, not a collection. That's why you can't iterate it with **foreach**.

Replace

```
public function comments() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\CommentModel');
}
```

with

```
public function comments() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\CommentModel', 'post_id');
}
```

You can read more about how to define different kinds of relationships with Eloquent here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Bro, when I change belongsTo to hasMany, then create a new error

(1) Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.post_model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `comments` where `comments`.`post_model_id` = 1 and `comments`.`post_model_id` is not null) (View: E:\Project\htdocs\lara_blog\resources\views\blog\single.blade.php)

(2)Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.post_model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `comments` where `comments`.`post_model_id` = 1 and `comments`.`post_model_id` is not null)

Comment: That's because your foreign key name doesn't match the model name - why do you need that Model suffix? Anyway, I've updated the answer

Comment: Sorry Bro, This message showing me. 

Thanks for the feedback. Votes cast by those with less then 15 reputation are recorded, but do not changes the publicity displayed post score.

Comment: Voting and marking as answered are 2 different things - as you are the asker you'll be able to mark a question as answered. See the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers